# dynamic text disappearance when loaded in another SWF

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text

I have a project ongoing at the moment that uses dynamic text blocks to form menu items and general project information. When loaded and run directly, everything is completely fine. However when i load the same movie through a loader flash, some (not all) of the text fields disappear.

All of the textfields are created on stage and have the correct font listed. I can trace the text fine, so it is applying ok. obviously the font is embedded because some of the text fields work, and all use the `embedFonts = true`, so it isnt a case of not looking for the right font.

Any ideas to stop me breaking my head against a wall would be appreciated

Example here:

[loaded Directly](http://andrewlongstaff.com/popup/indexdirect.html)

[loaded through loader](http://andrewlongstaff.com/popup/index.html)

**EDIT**

to be specific: the text fields that are on the "tabs" at the top and all of the main information panel texts are the ones that are the issue.

Comment: All of the textfields in the first link appear in the second link for me. 

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't click any of the links, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had duplicated symbols from the main flash into the loader to provide a consistent loading animation, however i didnt unlink them from the class, therefore they overwrote the main animation when called, and they didnt have the right fonts embedded.